# Let $A\in \mathbb C$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix, let $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots a_nx^n$ be any polynomial over $\mathbb C$. Comment on $f(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in \mathbb C$ be a $2 \times 2$  matrix, let $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots a_nx^n$ be any polynomial over $ \mathbb C$. Then which of the following is true?

a) $f(A)$ can be written as $c_0I+c_1A$, for some $c_0,c_1 \in \mathbb C$

b) $f(A)$ is zero matrix

c) The rank of $f(A)$ is $2$

d) $f(A)$ can never be the zero matrix

I'm guessing this uses Cayley-Hamilton theorem somehow, but $f(x)$is *any* polynomial, not necessarily the *characteristic* (or minimal) polynomial.

If $f(A)$ is the zero matrix, then rank cannot be true, so b is true implies c and d are false.  a can be true only if $c_0=0, c_1=0$, because then $c_0I+c_1A=0=f(A)$.

These are my ideas, please guide me to the correct line of proof. Thanks!

Comment: @goblin can you please explain a little how?

Comment: @goblin: If $a_0 \ne 0$ d) is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer a) is correct. Note that the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A$ of $A$ is of degree at most $2$, hence $f(x)=\chi_A(x)g(x)+c_1x+c_0$ for some poylnomial $g$ and constants $c_0,c_1$ (division with remainder).
Now plug in $A$ for $x$ and use $\chi_A(A)=0$.

b) is false because $f$ can be arbitrary, even constant nonzero

c) and d) are false because $f$ might be $\chi_A$ for example

Answer (score 1):

Let $\chi_A(x)$ be the characteristic polynomial of of $A$ (it has degree 2). Then by the division algorithm $f(x)=q(x)\chi_A(x)+r(x)$ where $\deg r<2$. Now, $f(A)=q(A)\chi_A(A)+r(A)=r(A)$ since $\chi_A(A)=0$. Since $\deg r<2$, $r(x)=c_0+c_1x$ for some $c_0,c_1\in\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right way with the Cayley-Hamilton theorem. Recall that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is of degree $2$ and use euclidean division on $f$ and the characteristic polynomial.